# How to find user location using cell tower in J2ME?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I just want to find the location name using cell tower in j2me.

Also how to redirect the incoming call to our own application from where the caller number is shown to user like the normal calling information?

[as of now when some one calls someone the mobile number is shown,]

I want to show the receiver of the call the location of the caller with his/her mobile number.

Comment: did you mean area name (cellinfo) ?

Comment: Yes, area name(cell info) only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Cell info is broadcasted as CBS (Cell Broadcast Service) message by the cell towers and received by all the GSM phones connected to this tower on certain predefined Channel (generally 050) by most of the service providers. Thus our Java ME application can listen to this CBS Channel using Push Registry and capture this information.

Follow the steps,

1. Import libraries

   ```
   import javax.wireless.messaging.*;
   import javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry;
   ```
2. Register your Midlet for Listening to CBS port 50 and setup a Message Listener

   ```
   public void setupListening()
   {        
       try{
       PushRegistry.registerConnection("cbs://:50",this.getClass().getName(),"*");
       }catch(Exception e){}
       String[] connList;
       connList = PushRegistry.listConnections(true);
   if((connList == null) || (connList.length == 0))
   {
     // You can exit the app, if you want
   }
   else 
       { 
       try{
       msgconn = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("cbs://:50");
           msgconn.setMessageListener(this);
       } catch( IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
        }
   }
   ```
3. To Retrieve the CBS message payload.

   ```
   public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn)
   {
     try{
           txtmsg =(TextMessage)msgconn.receive();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        from = txtmsg.getAddress());
        Msg = txtmsg.getPayloadText();
       // Display from & Msg            
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the post, i am very new guy to j2mee, i also want to redirect if any call comes to the user to the above application and than show the user the caller number and the cell info from where he/she calls. thanks for the patience and your post once again

Comment: +1 for the use of PushRegistry with cbs protocol, although I agree with @funkybro that it might not actually be the proper answer.

Comment: actual argument HelloWorldMidlet cannot be converted to javax.wireless.messaging.MessageListener by method invocation conversion
in this line msgconn.setMessageListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to find the location name using cell tower in j2me.

@Lucifer's method will show you your own current Cell ID information on certain networks when the device is not in 3G mode.

> Also how to redirect the incoming call to our own application from where the caller number is shown to user like the normal calling information?
>
> [as of now when some one calls someone the mobile number is shown,]

Not possible in J2ME.

> I want to show the receiver of the call the location of the caller with his/her mobile number.

Not possible at all!  Your cell ID refers to YOUR location, not that of a caller.  Even if there were a way of routing incoming call info to a J2ME app, all you would be able to show is country information (e.g. a number beginning +44 is definitely UK), and if the number were a land-line, some high-level location information (e.g. a number beginning +441234 is Bedford, UK).

---